# What's the meaning of AB in AB|C in TypeScript specification?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I'm checking TypeScript specification and at some point at [3.4 Union Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) 
it uses `AB` as follows:

- A | B is equivalent to A if B is a subtype of A.
- A | B is equivalent to B | A.
- AB | C is equivalent to A | BC, where AB is A | B and BC is B | C.

**Question:** What's the meaning of `AB` or `AB|C`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This section in the spec was written before parentheses were allowed in union types, hence the awkward phrasing.

A more clear formulation that says what this section is trying to say is:

> (A | B) | C is equivalent to A | (B | C)

Answer (score 3):

It's answered in your question:

AB = A|B

AB|C - is equivalent to A if C is a subtype of A and B is a subtype of A